# How do i truncated part of a word with a wildcard using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, wildcard

I have in Column AJ a lot of text strings (categories separated by ;#) example is Cell AJ2 has (Accounting: and some text;#Business: and some text) in each row. I want to delete specific string of categories and anything that follows it in column AJ that starts with "Business:" or ":#Business:

[image]

Comment: search for "vba excel regex"   ... this is the top hit  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops#22542835

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vSplit, s As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    vDB = Range("aj2", Range("aj" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        If InStr(s, "Business") Then
            vSplit = Split(s, "Business")
            s = Replace(s, "Business" & vSplit(UBound(vSplit)), "")
            If Right(s, 1) = "#" Then
                s = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)
            End If
            vDB(i, 1) = s
        End If
    Next i
    Range("ak2").Resize(n) = vDB
End Sub
```

Comment: If I want to delete everything before Business.

Comment: Dim vDB, vSplit, s As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    vDB = Range("aj2", Range("aj" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        If InStr(s, "Business") Then
            vSplit = Split(s, "Business")
            vDB(i, 1) = "Business" & vSplit(UBound(vSplit))
        Else
            vDB(i, 1) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    Range("ak2").Resize(n) = vDB

Comment: I added more sample data to delete everything before business. I updated the post with a sample image. I highlighted a row.. There are two businesses, so when I run the code, in the comment,  to delete everything before business, it works perfectly but it only shows one Business for the highlighted row.

Comment: Sub test3()
    Dim vDB, vSplit, s As String
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, k As Integer
    vDB = Range("aj2", Range("aj" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    n = UBound(vDB, 1)
    For i = 1 To n
        s = vDB(i, 1)
        If InStr(s, "Business") Then
            k = InStr(s, "Business") - 1
            vDB(i, 1) = Right(s, Len(s) - k)
        Else
            vDB(i, 1) = Empty
        End If
    Next i
    Range("ak2").Resize(n) = vDB
End Sub